# Adding multiple proximity Alerts

Tags: android, android-intent, proximity, android-pendingintent

I have a question... im developing one application that involves proximityAlerts...
in short i have 'n' number of POI's (Point of interest) in my application, so when i reach to that particular POI i should send an sms to a group of peoples when retrieved from the database...

sms sending and Database part is working fine.

Problem:
Implementing multiple proximity alerts.
creating pending Intents.
Then how to call sms sending class to fire an sms when i reach particular POI..

Im exhausted trying this ...
can anybody please help me to implement this part..

Thanx in advance..
Waiting for ur replies